# how to group two columns in one

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

i have three tables

customer,
people,
companies

tables people and companies have a "customerID"

table people have "cpf"
and
table companies have "cnpj"

i need to query

customerID, (cpf OR cnpj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a union should do the trick. Give this a try:

```
(SELECT customerID, cpf as cpfORcnpj FROM people )
UNION 
(SELECT customerID, cnpj as cpfORcnpj FROM companies)
```